# can't get javascript object property value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have javascript code like this

```js
for (let x = 0; x < result.data.length; x++) {
  let tankMaterial = await readTank(result.data[x].tank_id);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tankMaterial));

  parseObj[x] = {
    tank_id: result.data[x].tank_id,
    tank_name: result.data[x].tank_name,
    temperature: result.data[x].temperature,
    level_percent: Number.parseFloat(scale(result.data[x].pressure)).toFixed(2),
    level_raw: result.data[x].pressure,
    level_metric: (result.data[x].pressure * 6894.76) / (1000 * 9.8),
  };
}
```

the result from the console.log is:

```
{"id_material":"1","height":50,"diameter":25,"name":"CPO"}
```

I try to extract "name" property value from the "tankMaterial" object with code like :

```js
for (let x = 0; x < result.data.length; x++) {
  let tankMaterial = await readTank(result.data[x].tank_id);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tankMaterial.name));

  parseObj[x] = {
    tank_id: result.data[x].tank_id,
    tank_name: result.data[x].tank_name,
    temperature: result.data[x].temperature,
    level_percent: Number.parseFloat(scale(result.data[x].pressure)).toFixed(2),
    level_raw: result.data[x].pressure,
    level_metric: (result.data[x].pressure * 6894.76) / (1000 * 9.8),
  };
}
```

but it always gives an error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at TankData (/var/www/html/demo1/api/TankData.js:20:43)
```

I've been trying to access another property from tankMaterial object but the result always the same.

why can't I access the value of the tankMaterial object?

Comment: You cant access it because its undefined :) check my answer which explains it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let parseObj = [];
async function test(result) {
for (let index = 0; index < result.data.length; index ++) {
currentValue = result.data[index]
  // for (let currentValue of result.data) { can be used for good reading but 'continue' cannot be used
    let tankMaterial = await readTank(currentValue.tank_id).catch(() => {
      console.error('This promise failed')
      continue; // continue to next loop if some error in loop
    });
    console.log(tankMaterial) // this will be undefined if your promise has failed and you //if u don't use continue and start parsing/stringify it will throw you an error 

    try {
      console.log(tankMaterial.name)// if tankMaterial is undefined then u will get 'Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error) // log the error in case failure in your case name is not property of undefined 
    }

    console.log(tankMaterial);// {"id_material":"1","height":50,"diameter":25,"name":"CPO"}

    parseObj[index] = {
      tank_id: currentValue.tank_id,
      tank_name: currentValue.tank_name,
      temperature: currentValue.temperature,
      level_percent: Number.parseFloat(scale(currentValue.pressure)).toFixed(2),
      level_raw: currentValue.pressure,
      level_metric: (currentValue.pressure * 6894.76) / (1000 * 9.8),
    };
  }
}
```

- Always write your code such that it is readable
- Catch all those errors so that you know where exactly the error occurred
- I have refactored this code its should be easy to fix your issue now...
  Happy coding :)

Comment: Thankyou for the solution. the problem is caused by unproper error handling.  i implement   `try catch` and the error can be handled properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `JSON.parse(tankMaterial).name` to access it

Comment: i've been try it and the error changed into
`
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at TankData (/var/www/html/demo1/api/TankData.js:20:20)
`

Comment: can you share the result from `await readTank(result.data[x].tank_id)` without JSON.stringify?

Comment: the result without JSON.stringify is `{ id_material: '1', height: 50, diameter: 25, name: 'CPO' }`

Comment: Can you try to read it directly? `tankMaterial.name`

Comment: no, i;ve been try to read it direcly and parse it to another variable. the result is always ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: I need more info to figure the issue out. Can you create a minimum reproducible version on codesandbox or jsbin?